# How to import a file to React in a webfile

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to import a file to my main js file in react but it
s not working. I am using react cdn links for this webiste.How can i solve this. Please Assist.

```
<!---main file html---->
<body>
<div class="root"></div>
<script src="practise.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>

<!---practise.js---->
import HeaderInfo from Header
function Page(){
return (
 <HeaderInfo/><Reasons/>)
)}
ReactDOM.render(<Page/>,document.querySelector(".root")
<!---Header.js---->
export default function HeaderInfo(){
return (<h1>Hello World</h1>)}
```

Comment: If you want to import a js from other js in the browser you may consider [es module](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-modules). Otherwise use a bundler, such as wepack, to bundle your code first.

Comment: And if you're using JSX tags in your code you may need to change the extension from .js to .jsx and then transpile it.